# Does this answer your question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

This is the text that appears underneath a question when you flag it as a duplicate. I don't think it is helpful to the OP, especially if they are new.

The point is NOT that you think there is a good answer to their question in the referred to question, it is that it is a duplicated question.

In my view the text that appears should say something like "This question appears to have been asked before and has attracted one or more answers."

Comment: The current text is a bit rude and more than a bit blunt, especially as seen from the eyes of a newbie. A stated goal of the entire SO/SE network is to be more welcoming than in the past.

Comment: The language of the text has only recently been changed to *Does this answer your question...*, it used to say *Possible duplicate...* which, I think, was more polite.

Comment: Actually, years ago I thought the message was something like "This question *has been* asked before...." Anyway, does "text that appears *underneath* a question" = comment? The comment is autogenerated, but in a way that shows it being posted by a user - *I think* the first user to propose the duplicate. That user is then able to *edit* the comment for five minutes and customize it to something more appropriate for the given situation, or at any time that user can just delete it. I'm all in for a better message, but I think it needs to be a change across the entire network?